Is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,e^{-ikx}H_0^{(2)}(a\sqrt{b^2-x^2})=2i\frac{e^{-ib\sqrt{a^2+k^2}}}{\sqrt{a^2+k^2}}$ true? (Gradshteyn and Ryzhik 6.616.4)
After encountering a tricky integral of the Hankel function of the second kind, I was happy to find it almost exactly in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik as entry 6.616.4, namely
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}kx}H_0^{(2)}(a\sqrt{b^2-x^2})=2\mathrm{i}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}b\sqrt{a^2+k^2}}}{\sqrt{a^2+k^2}}.$$
However, after doing some numerical evaluations of the Fourier transform in Mathematica 14, I found that it did not give the correct answer (actually, it didn't converge because $\mathrm{Re}(H_0^{(2)}(a\sqrt{b^2-x^2}))\to\infty$ for $x\to\pm\infty$). A very similar entry, 6.616.3,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}kx}H_0^{(1)}(a\sqrt{b^2-x^2})=-2\mathrm{i}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}b\sqrt{a^2+k^2}}}{\sqrt{a^2+k^2}},$$
with the Hankel function of the first kind worked fine and is, in fact, just the complex conjugate of the first identity. Now I'm not sure if this is a mistake and the answer from 6.616.4 is somehow wrong (which I doubt), or if I'm just missing something. I have already made sure that the conditions on the parameters are met.
Edit: In the end I looking for the Fourier transform of $$\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}t\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$
if someone happens to know it.
Edit 2: After taking @Sal's comment into account, I think the correct version for 6.616.4 should be
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{d}x\, \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}kx}[H_0^{(1)}(a\sqrt{b^2-x^2})-2\mathrm{i}\mathrm{Re}(Y_0(a\sqrt{b^2-x^2}))]=2\mathrm{i}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}b\sqrt{a^2+k^2}}}{\sqrt{a^2+k^2}}$$
because the argument of the Hankel function is imaginary for $x>b$, and in this case its complex conjugate isn't $H_0^{(2)}$ but actually $-H_0^{(1)}$. This also seems to hold numerically.
Edit 3: Okay, I managed to find the inverse Fourier transform of $\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}t\sqrt{1+x^2}}$:
$$\cos(kt)-\frac{t}{2}\int_{-t}^t\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{H^{(2)}_1(\sqrt{t^2-x^2})}{\sqrt{t^2-x^2}}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}kx}+\frac{\mathrm{i} t}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus(-t,t)}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{K_1(\sqrt{x^2-t^2})}{\sqrt{x^2-t^2}}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}kx},$$
which is equivalent to
$$\cos(kt)-\frac{t}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{H^{(1)}_1(\sqrt{t^2-x^2})}{\sqrt{t^2-x^2}}\right)-\mathrm{i}\,\mathrm{Im}\left(\frac{H^{(1)}_1(\sqrt{t^2-x^2})}{\sqrt{t^2-x^2}}\right)\right]\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}kx}.$$
I wasn't able to simplify it any further.

If for the root you take $\sqrt{b^2-x^2}\to-i\sqrt{x^2-b^2}$ in the region where $x>b$ then I believe the first expression is correct
